# In Angular, how can I manipulate my result objects before my http get returns them?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-http

My web service returns a bunch of objects and I'd like to manipulate those objects, by changing the "state" field into something else, before my Angular service sends them to the consuming component.

I've tried iterating through the array with a map and replacing the field with the translated field, but that does not appear to work (even though console.log shows that the job.state does change):

```
return this.http
        .get(this.jobsUrl, options)
        .map(res => {
            console.log(job.state);  //shows original value
            res.json().jobs.map((job) => job.state = this.stateTranslation[job.state]);
            console.log(job.state);  //shows translated value
            return res.json().jobs as Job[];
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Perhaps map just returns a copy of "job" and that the original object isn't really getting modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 2 maps. 1 for converting to `JSON`, and another one to loop through the array. This increases readability. The issue you are having is that you call `res.json` twice, which means that the change you do to the first array, never reaches the second one.

```
return this.http
    .get(this.jobsUrl, options)
    .map(res => res.json().jobs as Job[])
    .map((job: Job) =>  {
       job.state = this.stateTranslation[job.state]);
       return job;
    }) 
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the result after the map and return the job after changing it's state in the array map callback:

```
return this.http
        .get(this.jobsUrl, options)
        .map(res => {
            let ret = res.json().jobs.map((job) => { 
                job.state = this.stateTranslation[job.state];
                return job;
             });
            return ret as Job[];
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
```